# Heroku images won't work

Tags: image, angular, heroku, mlab

I'm having the strangest issue with my Heroku App. None except one of the images I pushed on there loads in production. All I get is a 404 error. They work fine locally. I know it isn't the path because...well, here's a sample of the mlab collection. The no_image_thumb.gif image works just fine, but the other images like HG01522.jpg just return a 404 error.

```js
{
            "id": 794,
            "itemno": "HG01522",
            "image": "images/prodimg/HG01522.jpg",
            "name": "FIXED SNAP SHACKLES",
            "price": 25.25,
            "dfec": 68.175,
            "dpec": 95.87327535,
            "category": "BOATHARDWA",
            "selected": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 795,
            "itemno": "HG01602",
            "image": "images/prodimg/no_image_thumb.gif",
            "name": "SHACKLE LOCKING  316 8MM",
            "price": 12.3,
            "dfec": 33.21,
            "dpec": 46.70262522,
            "category": "BOATHARDWA",
            "selected": 0
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you must store the image etc.. on an external place... for example S3 or something... heroku not accept static files...

Comment: Your images are part of code or they uploaded from your website?

Comment: Do you know of any service other than s3 where I can store them? @PierangeloOrizio

Comment: Uploaded @karthikdivi

Comment: you can try also with dropbox, google drive... or on a your vps or hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are part of code or they uploaded from your website? 
If its second one then you are doing it wrong. Heroku re-deploy your app every day and you loose your images. So go for services like aws s3 or cloudinary